# Recompiling an old fortran 2/4\66 program that was compiled for os\2 need it to run in dos

Tags: compiler-construction, fortran

I am helping an old scientist with some problems and have 1 program that he found and
modified about 20 yrs. ago, and runs fine as a 32 bit os\2 executable but i need it to
run under dos! I am not a programmer but a good hardware & software man, so I'am 
pretty stupid about this problem, but here go's  I have downloaded 6 different
compilers watcom77,silverfrost ftn95,gfortran,2 versions of g77 and f80. Watcom
says it is to old of program,find older compiler,silverfrost opens it,debugs, etc.
but is changing all the subroutines from "real" to "complex" and vice-vesa,and 
the g77's seem to install perfectly (library links and etc.) but wont even compile
the test.f programs.My problem is 1; to recompile "as is" or "upgrade" the code?
    PROGRAM  xconvlv
    INTEGER N,N2,M

```
PARAMETER  (N=2048,N2=2048,M=128)
INTEGER  i,isign
REAL data(n),respns(m),resp(n),ans(n2),t3(n),DUMMY
OPEN(UNIT=1, FILE='C:\QKBAS20\FDATA1.DAT')
DO 1 i=1,N
  READ(1,*) T3(i), data(i), DUMMY
continue
  CLOSE(UNIT-1)
do  12 i=1,N
  respns(i)=data(i)
  resp(i)=respns(i)
continue
isign=-1
call  convlv(data,N,resp,M,isign,ans)
  OPEN(UNIT=1,FILE='C:\QKBAS20\FDATA9.DAT')
  DO 14 i=1,N
  WRITE(1,*)  T3(i), ans(i)
   continue
END
SUBROUTINE CONVLV(data,n,respns,m,isign,ans)
INTEGER  isign,m,n,NMAX
REAL data(n),respns(n)
COMPLEX ans(n)
PARAMETER (NMAX=4096)
* uses realft, twofft
INTEGER i,no2
COMPLEX fft (NMAX)
do 11 i=1, (m-1)/2
  respns(n+1-i)=respns(m+1-i)
continue
do 12 i=(m+3)/2,n-(m-1)/2
  respns(i)=0.0
continue
call twofft (data,respns,fft,ans,n)
no2=n/2
do 13 i=1,no2+1
  if (isign.eq.1) then
    ans(i)=fft(i)*ans(i)/no2
  else if (isign.eq.-1) then
    if (abs(ans(i)) .eq.0.0) pause
    ans(i)=fft(i)/ans(i)/no2
  else
    pause 'no meaning for isign in convlv'
  endif
continue
ans(1)=cmplx(real (ans(1)),real (ans(no2+1)))
call realft(ans,n,-1)
return
END

SUBROUTINE realft(data,n,isign)
INTEGER isign,n
REAL data(n)
* uses four1
INTEGER i,i1,i2,i3,i4,n2p3
REAL c1,c2,hli,hir,h2i,h2r,wis,wrs
DOUBLE PRECISION theta,wi,wpi,wpr,wr,wtemp
theta=3.141592653589793d0/dble(n/2)
cl=0.5
if  (isign.eq.1) then
  c2=-0.5
  call four1(data,n/2,+1)
else
  c2=0.5
  theta=-theta
endif
 (etc.,etc., etc.)


SUBROUTINE twofft(data,data2,fft1,fft2,n)
INTEGER n
REAL data1(n,data2(n)
COMPLEX fft1(n), fft2(n)
* uses four1
INTEGER j,n2
COMPLEX h1,h2,c1,c2
c1=cmplx(0.5,0.0)
c2=cmplx(0.0,-0.5)
do 11 j=1,n
  fft1(j)=cmplx(data1(j),data2(j)
continue
call four1 (fft1,n,1)
fft2(1)=cmplx(aimag(fft1(1)),0.0)
fft1(1)=cmplx(real(fft1(1)),0.0)
n2=n+2
do 12 j=2,n/2+1
  h1=c1*(fft1(j)+conjg(fft1(n2-j)))
  h2=c2*(fft1(j)-conjg(fft1(n2-j)))
  fft1(j)=h1
  fft1(n2-j)=conjg(h1)
  fft2(j)=h2
  fft2(n2-j)=conjg(h2)
continue
return
END

SUBROUTINE four1(data,nn,isign)
INTEGER isign,nn
REAL data(2*nn)
INTEGER i,istep,j,m,mmax,n
REAL tempi,tempr
DOUBLE PRECISION theta, wi,wpi,wpr,wr,wtemp
n=2*nn
j=1
do 11 i=1,n,2
  if(j.gt.i)then
    tempr=data(j)
    tempi=data(j+1)
(etc.,etc.,etc.,)
continue
mmax=istep
goto 2
endif
return
END
```

There are 4 subroutines with this that are about 3 pages of code and whould be much
easier to e-mail to someone if their able to help me with this.My e-mail is
mastermikie4356@yahoo.com , or if someone could tell me where to get a "working"
compiler that could recompile this?
THANK-YOU, THANK-YOU,and THANK-YOU for any help with this!
The errors Iam getting are;
1.In a call to CONVLV from another procedure,the first argument was of a type
  REAL(kind=1), it is now a COMPLEX(kind=1)
2.In a call to REALFT from another procedure, ... COMPLEX(kind=1) it is now
  a REAL(kind=1)
3.In a call to TWOFFT from...COMPLEX(kind-1) it is now a REAL(kind=1)
4.In a previous call to FOUR1, the first argument was of a type REAL(kind=1)
  it is now a COMPLEX(kind=1).

Answer (score 0):

On a quick reading of the program I don't see any major problems.   The file names are "hardcoded" into the open statements -- you may need to may need to change those to match their location on whatever computer that you are porting the program to.

For FORTRAN 77, the source code other than line numbers should start in column 7.

If you want more specific advice, show us the error messages.

I suggest trying with one or two compiling and figuring out the changes necessary with the code rather than installing numerous compilers with the idea that somehow one will get the program working.

Comment: Thank-you for ypur answer,here are the acsess violtions iam getting

Answer (score 0):

The error messages indicate that there is an argument mismatch between the calling routine and the subroutine (sending type REAL, expecting type COMPLEX).
This might be a mistake, or more likely, some non-standard trick that worked on older compilers but doesn't work on newer compilers.

Can you post the headers from each of the subroutines?  (or a link to the entire program?)

Comment: I don't have a site to link this to but will email it to you